# When testing an ExpressJS route using mocha+sinon, how do you "stub" a function that's local to the route?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, sinon

So in one file, I have this route defined:

```
router.post('/', security.authenticate, function(req, res, next) {
    //Doing prep stuff

    //Do database work (<< this is what im really testing for)

    //Calling another work function.
    createFormUser(req.body, (ret) => {
        return res.json(ret.createdUser);
    });

});
```

followed by this function:

```
var createFormUser = (ourUser, call) => {
    // does a bunch of misc work and creation for another database
    // unrelated to current tests.
}
```

I want to to test this route. Normally, I would just create a sandbox instance of the database so that it can do whatever it wants, make an http request to the route in the test, and finally do expects() in the return from that http call.

However, I don't want the "createFormUser" function to be called, because 1) it does some fancy shit that's really hard to contain for this test 2) I will be testing it elsewhere.

In a normal test I would at this point use sinon to stub the function. But in this case I don't actually have an object reference, since this is all done through HTTP requests to server that mocha spools up when testing.

So my question is the same as the title, how can stub/replace/ignore/etc this method so it doesn't get called during the test?

Comment: An extremely dumb and hacky solution I cam up with, is to define another route to set a global variable in the file, that I can test against and not make the function call if it's set.

I think this is a terrible solution through and would much rather do it the  "right way", if such a way exists.

Comment: Where does `createFormUser` come from? Is it an argument to a function which contains your snippet? Is it imported with `require`? Or is it defined in this file? If so, is it exported?

Comment: It's defined in the file exactly as shown a few lines down after the route deceleration. I'm going to be first ti admit that im still very new to all of this, so if I'm doing it wrong please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being blind. But if you export `createFormUser` then you can write unit tests where it's stubbed out, and you can also write separate unit tests to make sure `createFormUser` does what it's supposed to.

Comment: I was actually going to reply yesterday, but I forgot to do that.

Yeah, That's pretty much how I solved it. I guess you can see just how new I am with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @DavidKnipe, all I had to do was export the methods via:

```
module.exports.createFormUser = (ourUser, call) => { ... }
```

And was able to both test the method individually and prevent it's execution via a sinon.stub.